# backbone.js using image urls from a folder as object attributes

Tags: backbone.js, binding, collections, view, models

I'm pulling my backbone models from an array that I'm generating from a folder on the server containing images; first I get the list of images using PHP, than I pass the array into a javascript array, finally I loop through my javascript array in backbone creating a new view for each image,
when a new image is uploaded, this also creates a new object, but can anyone give me a suggestion as to how I could save attributes of the object, for example {name:pizza} on my server or in a database, so that on page reload these attributes will persist. Or is there an alternative way to do this?

Comment: Use `Model.save` (http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save).

Comment: @fencliff question -> so first I use Model.fetch to pull my list of image from the server correct? When I use model.save , will my saved attributes be saved to a specific file or can I just pick a directory? Do I need a text file in any specific format to save these attributes?